# Bribery in a bad situation

Tags: halal-haram

Someone is threatening to say something about me at school that can cause me a lot of trouble(not physical harm) from other students.
I told him I would give him $20 if he didn't say anything.I have given him $9 and will give him the rest tomorrow. Is this haram since it's somewhat bribery or is it okay because I'm hiding a sin? If it's haram should I not give him the money and try to get the rest back(he will tell everyone if I do this) or should I show him a passage about bribery in Islam(he isn't a very religious person) or should I give him the rest of the money?(I am not baligh yet)

Comment: However I may be baligh

Comment: as far as I know, bribery is strictly prohibited when someone is luring money of the innocent by bribing the higher authorities.

Comment: You have not told us what the "something" is that you do not want others to know. Is it something that is haram? Maybe you should worry about that instead of worrying about money.

Answer (score 1):

People usually shy when it come to sexual sins. So I suppose that is your problem. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I revise my statement. The witnesses may report your act of sin to the authority for you to receive punishment. For this, he isn't allowed to accept any bribery and you aren't allowed to bribe.

Unless you have received your punishment, and insyaAllah Allah forgive you, those who spread your sins is those who indeed, have sinned.

Bribe in certain conditions, when you have to bribe to get your rights (example, when having a bad authority), is allowed.

Bribe to avoid responsibility and to steal  other rights, is forbidden.

Comment: Are you sure about this "**Sins is not for public, hiding it with bribing should be allowed**"???

Comment: That's the only thing that I can came up with. Example, someone do adultery and had received the punishment. But one of the witnesses want to go to the public and shout out that Fulan ibn Fulan has commited adultery. I used the statement that Allah forbid one to spread one sin. If there is something against this statement, please post it so I can revise my answer

Comment: I don't know, I highly feel you're idea might be wrong,, does this even prevail amongst people or is ur idea from scratch?...plz consult more people, I give no comments on this,,,,anyways, that question is likely to get closed.

Comment: I revised the answer after few contemplation. Jazakallah